# Conditional Merging in SAS

Tags: sas

***Hi all i have the below two datasets in which i need to map Date1 with Date2 in a range of (+/- 7)days within an ID.***

```
    Data set1;
    input ID  Date1 ddmmyy8.;
    Format Date1 Date11.;
    Datalines;
    001 02-08-15
    001 04-08-15
    001 06-08-15
    002 11-09-15
    002 14-09-15
    002 17-09-15
    ;
    run;

    Data set2;
    input ID TYPE $ Date2 ddmmyy8.;
    Format Date2 Date11.;
    Datalines;
    001 TYPE1 02-08-15
    001 TYPE2 11-08-15
    001 TYPE3 06-08-15
    002 TYPE1 07-09-15
    002 TYPE2 04-09-15
    002 TYPE3 09-08-15
    ;
    run;


    Proc sql;
create table out as select a.ID, a.Date1, b.Date2,
intck('days', Date1, Date2) as Diff
from set1 as a full join set2 as b
on a.ID = b.ID and (Date1 + 7 >= Date2 >= Date1 - 7)
group by a.ID, Date1 having diff = min(diff);
quit;
```

*I get the below output*
[image]

*i need output*
[image]

*Expected Output*

[image]

***The output i get is highlighted in yellow when i map using min of Diff.
but the output i need is highlighted in green it is because i have to maintain the values in Date2 as distinct and does not repeat.

(i.e) Because 02-Aug-2015 is already mapped with 02-Aug-2015 as well as 09-Aug-2015 mapped with 09-Aug-2015 of Date1 i need the 04-Aug-2015 of Date1 to be mapped with the remaining 11-Aug-2015***

Comment: I don't see any OCT dates in the question.  To simplify (*leaving off the month and year*) do you want to eliminate combo 04:02 because 02:02  occurs 'first' datewise ? What about 04:06, want or not want ? Should it be not want because 02:06 exists before 04:06 ?

Comment: Hi richard thank you for notifying the mismatch in month. It is August and not october.

Comment: first of all because of maintain the distinct values in  Dataset1 (i.e) i need 02 aug, 04 aug & 06 aug to appear only once in output as in source dataset. Likewise i need the values in Dataset2 (i.e) 02 aug, 06 aug & 11 aug to appear only once.

Comment: i have attached the expected output for your reference.

Comment: regarding *as well as*, 02-aug is not mapped to 09-aug.  it is mapped to 06-aug.  Why is there 04:11 and 06:06  ? Should the expected be 02:02 04:06 06:11 ?  Just trying to establish the actual 'rules'.

Comment: Hi Richard 09-Aug should not be in the picture as it has ID value 002 we are mapping values within ID values only. As for the logic we are mapping the Date1 and Date2 variable in the condition ((Date1 + 7) >= Date2 >= (Date1 - 7))  where we are giving the first preference for equalness (Date1=Date2) then the second preference is the lowest value of diff (if Date1 != Date2 then the min diff value) but also maintaining the distinctive manner.

Comment: Here  02:02 are equal dates hence given first preference and the 02 in both datasets are already reserved. hence now we would have only 04 & 06 in Dataset 1 and 06 & 11 in dataset 2. Now that 06:06 are same dates we have to map them, therefore we would be having the only 04 in dataset 1 and 11 in dataset 2 which are also within range ((Date1 + 7) >= Date2 >= (Date1 - 7)) hence we have to map remaining 04:11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So judging on the comments above the rules are quite complex: 
* join based on ID
* Absolute difference between date 1 and date 2 should be less then 7
* Preference for matching dates should be given to dates that are equal
* In case dates aren't equal, the solution should be so that as much as combinations are 
  returned as possible
* Date1 & Date2 need to be unique

I'm not sure whether the solution can be done in one proc sql step. 
You can't just work with a simple rule as it is not always the result with the lowest difference between dates that needs to be returned. Next to that, you need to sort of 'remember' which dates per ID you have selected for an output since you can't select them anymore further on.

First I made an inner join on ID where the difference in dates was <= 7. This gives all possible valid combinations. Then I've put all the dates where the difference in dates was 0 in a macro variable so I can make a table of all possible combinations except dates being in the macro variable. In the last step then you want to have the solution returning the most possible combinations of date1 - date2 where both are distinct.

```
 Data set1;
 input ID  Date1 ddmmyy8.;
 Format Date1 Date11.;
 Datalines;
 001 02-08-15
 001 04-08-15
 001 06-08-15
 002 11-09-15
 002 14-09-15
 002 17-09-15
 ;
 run;

Data set2;
input ID TYPE $ Date2 ddmmyy8.;
Format Date2 Date11.;
Datalines;
001 TYPE1 02-08-15
001 TYPE2 11-08-15
001 TYPE3 06-08-15
002 TYPE1 07-09-15
002 TYPE2 04-09-15
002 TYPE3 09-08-15
;
run;

Proc sql noprint;
/*Create a macro variable with all the dates for which the difference between date1 
and date2 = 0 */
select distinct put(Date1,yymmddn8.) into: dates seperated by ','
from set1 as a inner join set2 as b
on a.ID = b.ID and abs(intck('days', Date1, Date2)) = 0;

/*Create table with all lines where difference <= 7 but date is not in the ones with 
difference = 0 */
create table out as select a.ID, a.Date1, b.Date2,
intck('days', Date1, Date2) as Diff
from set1 as a inner join set2 as b
on a.ID = b.ID where abs(intck('days', Date1, Date2)) <= 7 and 
find("&dates.",put(Date1,yymmddn8.)) = 0 and find("&dates.",put(Date2,yymmddn8.)) = 0;

/* Check the number of possible combinations */
create table out as
select a.*,
       b.cnt1 + c.cnt2 as combos
from out a left join (select distinct id,
                                  date1,
                                  count(*) as cnt1
                      from out
                      group by id, date1) b on a.date1 = b.date1 and a.id = b.id
           left join (select distinct id,
                                   date2,
                                   count(*) as cnt2
                      from out
                      group by id, date2) c on a.date2 = c.date2 and a.id = c.id
          order by id, combos;
 quit;

/* Select unique dates per date1, date2 */
data out(keep = id date1 date2);
   retain mem1 mem2;
   length mem1 mem2 $100.;

 set out;

 by id combos;

  if first.id then do;
      mem1 = "0";
      mem2 = "0";
  end;

  date10 = put(date1,yymmddn8.);
  date20 = put(date2,yymmddn8.);

  if find(mem1,date10) = 0 and find(mem2,date20) = 0 then do;
      mem1 = catx(',',mem1,date10);
      mem2 = catx(',',mem2,date20);
      output;
  end;      
run;

/* Create a union between lines with no difference in date and lines with difference 
in date*/
proc sql;
    create table final as
    select * from out
    union
    select a.ID, a.Date1, b.Date2 
    from set1 as a inner join set2 as b
    on a.ID = b.ID and abs(intck('days', Date1, Date2)) = 0;
quit;
```

So this gives a table like:

[Final Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDE8f.png)